# MVC3 validating a partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm still quite new to MVC so bear with me.

I have a simple view that contains a partial view. In that partial view model I have validation annotations like so:

```
public class LocationViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Area")]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    public int? AreaId { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AWS.DTO.Lookup> Areas { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Establishment")]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    public int? EstablishmentId { get; set; }
    public string Establishment { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AWS.DTO.Lookup> Establishments { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Property")]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required.")]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AWS.DTO.Lookup> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Partial view:

```
    @model AWS.PL.ViewModels.LocationViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSEATs(area) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SelectSEATs", "Location")",
            data: { areaId: area },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = "";
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                });

                $("#SEATId").html(items);
            }
        });
    }

    function getEstablishments(seat) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SelectEstablishments", "Location")",
            data: { seatId: seat },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = "";
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                });

                $("#EstablishmentId").html(items);
            }
        });
    }

    function getProperties(estab) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SelectProperties", "Location")",
            data: { estabId: estab },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var items = "";
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                });

                $("#PropertyId").html(items);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AreaId").change(function () {
            var area = $("#AreaId").val();
            getSEATs(area);
        });
        $("#SEATId").change(function () {
            var seat = $("#SEATId").val();
            getEstablishments(seat);
        });
        $("#EstablishmentId").change(function () {
            var estab = $("#EstablishmentId").val();
            getProperties(estab);
        });
    });    
</script>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AreaId, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AreaId, new SelectList(Model.Areas, "ID", "Description", -1), "-- Please Select -- ")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SEATId, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SEATId, new SelectList(Model.SEATs, "ID", "Description", -1))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EstablishmentId, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EstablishmentId, new SelectList(Model.Establishments, "ID", "Description", -1))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertyId, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyId, new SelectList(Model.Properties, "ID", "Description", -1))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PropertyId)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I submit my main form the validation is fired for the fields on the main view, not the partial view. Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: What does your partial view lookup like?  What properties of the model are being used in your partial view?

Comment: I've added the partial view code. The main model uses the propertyid property.

Comment: Ahh, so that validation annotation needs to reside on the main property not the partial view model property??

Comment: What is the value of the dropdown in the generated html when you are submitting?  The required attribute checks if the field is not null or empty.  Since all of your Select inputs are going to be of an int type, I'm thinking you may need to change your PropertyId field type to int?, and change the default value of the dropdown to null.

Comment: Quite right, it's working now. Can I not mark this comment as the answer?

Comment: I've posted an answer so you can mark that.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: Are you talking about server validation or client validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the property field is a non-nullable int, the field will always be set to some value.  The required attribute only checks for empty or null fields, not default values. You'll need to change the type of the property to int?, and set the default value to null.